# What does the errors parameter do in the built-in python bytes() class?

Tags: python-3.x

The documentation doesn't seem to describe what it does. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes

I'm assuming its a typical pattern used in other functions (e.g. bytesarray) as well but I can't figure out what it does and not sure what to google for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description of [`bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) begins with:

> Firstly, the syntax for bytes literals is largely the same as that for string literals

Looking at [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str):

> If at least one of *encoding* or *errors* is given, *object* should be a bytes-like object (e.g. `bytes` or `bytearray`). In this case, if *object* is a `bytes` (or `bytearray`) object, then `str(bytes, encoding, errors)` is equivalent to `bytes.decode(encoding, errors)`.

[`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) says:

> *errors* may be given to set a different error handling scheme. The default for *errors* is `'strict'`, meaning that encoding errors raise a `UnicodeError`. Other possible values are `'ignore'`, `'replace'` and any other name registered via `codecs.register_error()`, see section Error Handlers.

So the purpose of `errors` is to define how to handle encoding errors in the data. The aforementioned [Error Handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) section contains more in-depth information.